# Is there something like "View Customizer" in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

There is [Tiles example](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/generic-tile-format) on Github. But this is JSON Column Formatting.

Is there a way to have more control above View rendering from SPFx web-part?

I know field customizers can change behavior for separate field, but what about the whole list view?

Can You please provide an example if exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

Currently there is no such View Customizer available in SharePoint Framework.

As you already know, currently you can only use [JSON formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) to customize your view in SharePoint Online.

**Useful Links**:

1. [SharePoint Framework roadmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/roadmap).
2. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Comment: Thank You Ganesh!